# How to automatically update my windows application WITHOUT prompting the user to do so?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, auto-update

I have seen there are many technologies out there that make auto updating easy for the user (such as winsparkle).  The problem we have is we want to be able to auto update our desktop (c#/c++) app without prompting.

If users have the ability to NOT update it makes our lives hell (10,000+ installs all need to be updated about once a month).

We currently install our application via WIX and it reinstalling a new version completely overwrites what was there before.  This works fine but we'd love to not even have to run the new installer, thus the idea of auto updating.

I've looked at clickonce but since our app is both a tray icon/windows forms app and a Windows Service it appears installing a service via ClickOnce is somewhat unfeasible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not clear - if you don't want to prompt user - than don't... Or there are actual reasons to do so that are not covered in the post?

Comment: Are you looking for a product that does this already, or for a design methodology to build your own? It's also not clear whether "We currently install our application via WIX and it reinstalling a new version completely overwrites what was there before" is a problem for you. If you install with an MSI package then you must update with an MSI update, a patch (.msp file) or another update. It looks like you are using major upgrade. Patch may be what you need.

Comment: [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx) could help you in this case.

Answer (score 2):

To do this update behavior you need two things:

1) An updater application which checks for updates regularly. If an update is found it should install it automatically. Most commercial setup authoring tools include good updater applications. You can try writing an updater yourself, but it's not as easy as it sounds.

2) Per-user installations for each of your product versions. A per-user installation writes data only in the user profile folder (AppData, Roaming folder etc.) and HKEY_CURRENT_USER. No Program Files or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Per-user installations are required so you can perform the upgrade silently. If the installation is per machine, newer Windows version will show the elevation prompt and the user won't know what's happening.

**The Updater**

Some updaters use services. For automated updates this isn't a real solution because service installation needs Administrator privileges. So your install process and subsequent updates would show elevation prompts.

Another approach is to use a per-user Updater application. It doesn't require any elevation and it can be installed in the application folder. This type of updater can run either as a scheduled task or from within your application (execute it when your application starts).

In both scenarios you need to consider that the Updater may need to update itself. So the process which performs the update must be a temporary process (for example a temporary copy of the updater application). It also should run without elevation. This is why a service is not such a good idea. It would need to stop itself before the update, use a temporary process which handles the update and start again when finished.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing for some applications that I manage, and that are written in C#.

I distribute an installer based on InnoSetup to deploy the files on the user system, and the application stores information version in the registry.
The application has a mechanism that checks at startup for available updates, and prompts the user. This system is based on a JSON manifest that contains a basic structure such as the following:

```
{
"releases": [
    {
        "CommitDate": "2020-09-05",
        "Version": "0.1.0.0",
        "VersionString": "0.1.0+19",
        "SHA": "4ff750da44b41e569daf3c62f4495a8ee2b25f08",
        "InstallerMd5Sum": "805497b5c13ee070b7465bb32689e0dd"
    },
    {
        "CommitDate": "2020-09-07",
        "Version": "0.1.0.0",
        "VersionString": "0.1.0+22",
        "SHA": "a04ec929b21230ba0e2577617713d10b106266e9",
        "InstallerMd5Sum": "805497b5c13ee070b7465bb32689e0dd"
    }
]}}
```

The application downloads that file and compares its local information with the latest entry in the file.

If the latest entry is more recent (based on things like commit date), it retrieves the installer from the distribution server, checks for integrity, and run the installer.

The installer takes care of updating the entries in the registry with the latest information.
Now, there are three angles to your question I believe.
The first one is whether a modularity is possible so that you don't end up replacing everything and can provide delta installers, the second is whether you can use a technology that knows how to deal with updates ([which I believe MSI knows how to do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/patching-and-upgrades)). Finally, the third angle is whether or not you have a way for users to rollback in case the latest version has issue with their system or whatever your application is for.